# Average number of tries needed before success

Tags: probability

- there is a 3% chance of success
- there are a thousand people trying over and over until they succeed
  how many tries will it take on average for the last person to achieve this success?

I know that the average person will need between 22 and 23 tries, and I think a normal distribution could be utilized to look at that 0.1% lowest percentile.
But I'm stuck on how to construct this curve and how to calculate the value linked to that 0.1% percentile.
(It's been 4 years since i've had statistics in college, so obviously i could be way off)

Comment: You mean between $33$ and $34$ trials on average. I can write down an infinite sum for your expectation of the maximum, but do not see a way to evaluate it in closed form.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm not sure what you mean by the infinite sum, but I did mean 22-23 times. This is since (32/33)^23 = 0.4927, which averages to about 50% chance of success.

Comment: For a single person, let random variable $X$ be the number of trials until the first success. We want the mean $E[X]$ of $X$. The probability of success is $p=0.03$. The random variable $X$ has a geometric distribution, parameter $p$. It is a standard result that $E[X]=\frac{1}{p}$.  If you instead find the $n$ such that $(0.97)^n\approx \frac{1}{2}$, you are calculating the **median** of $X$.  The usual interpretation of "on average" is mean, though median is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the probability of success on any one trial  be $p=0.03$, and suppose there are $n=1000$ people. We assume independence.

For $i=1$ to $n$, let $X_i$ be the number of trials  the $i$-th person makes before she succeeds. Let $Y=\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. We want $E(Y)$.

We have $Y\le k$ if and only if $X_i\le k$ for all $i$.  The probability that $X_i\le k$ is $1-\Pr(X_i\gt k)$, what is, $1-(1-p)^k$.  It follows that
$\Pr(Y\le k)=(1-(1-p)^k)^n$. But $\Pr(Y=k)=\Pr(Y\le k)-\Pr(Y\le k-1)$. Now we can write down an infinite sum for $E(Y)$. I don't see how to put this in closed form. There may not be a closed form.

**Remark:** If, as is possibly the case, you are interested in the **median** number of trials of the least lucky person, we want to find the largest $k$ such that $\Pr(Y\le k)\le \frac{1}{2}$. So, roughly speaking, we want to solve the equation
$$(1-(1-p)^k)^n =\frac{1}{2}.$$
This can be done using logarithms.